# How do i create a grid (Matrix 4xn) with checkboxes in vaadin?

Tags: java, grid, vaadin, grid-layout, vaadin7

I'm trying to create a grid matrix with checkboxes (see picture 1). But I want the checkboxes to be as big as the grid (see picture 2). How can I realize that? Is it possible in Vaadin to make the grid clickable, then you can leave the checkboxes out completely. Or is there another possibility such as buttons?

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2tPe.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jekMT.png)

I use Vaadin 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the Button class. Use the style BUTTON_LINK and have no caption. Then use resource icons to swap what is shown. The swapping of icons and saving state should be added as a click listener.